# Deleting a lifeline from a StarUML sequence diagram

Tags: sequence-diagram, staruml

How can I delete a lifeline from a sequence diagram in StarUML without deleting it from the model ?

I'm using the same lifeline in two different diagrams, but I can't delete from one of them.
When I hit `Delete`, I get the message `"selected view should be deleted from models"`

Answer (score 0):

You a probably using a `View Element` instead of a `Model Element`. The `View Element` is an element you have already used in your project and you apparently created it by drag-an-drop.

Try to delete the element by pressing `Ctrl+delete`. It should work